# What type of bonus is a Monk's bonus to AC?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monk, armor-class

What type of bonus is a Monk's AC bonus in Pathfinder, Natural, Deflect, Or some other type? All I know is that it's a Wisdom bonus.

Answer (score 6):

#### Monks add their Wisdom bonus and an untyped bonus to AC.

The [monk](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/)  in the Core Rulebook says the monk adds their Wisdom bonus to AC/CMD, and also adds an untyped bonus to AC/CMD.

> When unarmored and unencumbered, the monk adds his Wisdom bonus (if any) to his AC and his CMD. In addition, a monk gains a +1 bonus to AC and CMD at 4th level. This bonus increases by 1 for every four monk levels thereafter, up to a maximum of +5 at 20th level.
>
> These bonuses to AC apply even against touch attacks or when the monk is flat-footed. He loses these bonuses when he is immobilized or helpless, when he wears any armor, when he carries a shield, or when he carries a medium or heavy load.

It's neither natural armor, nor dodge, nor enhancement, nor deflection, nor luck, or any other [typed bonus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary/#Bonus). The monk's extra bonus AC is untyped.

The [unchained monk](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/monk-unchained/) has essentially the same class feature, with nearly identical wording.